# Net::SFTP::Foreign Cipher check

Tags: perl

I am using the Net::SFTP::Foreign module through perl script to connect to a SFTP server with below sample command:

Net::SFTP::Foreign->new($host, port => '22', backend => 'Net_SSH2')

Yesterday I got an email from the SFTP server team that says that they are restricting the allowed SSH Algorithms to the following:

Options (allowed Algorithms):

- Ciphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
- Macs: hmac-sha256,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha512,hmac-sha2-512
- Kexs: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp256

How do I know if I will be affected by this or not? How do I check the cipher the script is using?

Net::SFTP::Foreign->new($host, port => '22', backend => 'Net_SSH2')

Comment: Crossposted to [PerlMonks](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1231945).

Answer (score 0):

When one server connects to another one via SFTP, the both find common cipher to authenticate. As long as your production server has some of the cyphers provided in the email you should be able to connect. You might want to contact your system admins to get the list of installed cyphers.
The email that you got most like specifies the Test server to test the connection with new cyphers. Try to connect to that test server and see if you are able to.